# Salesforce Commerce Cloud Payment Setup Issue

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce

We are trying to setup the Salesforce Out of the Box Payment procedure for a B2B Commerce store created in LWR Template by following the below Salesforce Help Document.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.payments_commerce_integrations.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.payments_onboarding_intro.htm&type=5

As per the document, we have to Enable the Salesforce Payments in our Org to see the Payments App and to Setup the Merchant Account and Payment Method Set. But while we search in the settings >> Quick Find Box we are unable to see the payments option. Can someone please guide us how we can Setup the Payments for a B2B Commerce Store build in LWR Template.